# How come NetworkStream.DataAvailable is always true?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming

I open a `TcpClient` and then call `tcpClient.GetStream().Read(message, 0, 8)` in order to read messages from the connection.

For some reason I keep getting garbage data even though the other side of the connection does not send any data. `Read()` never blocks, `DataAvailable` is always `true`, and I get a lot of garbage as the data.

What could be the reason?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you check the return value of `Read`? In non blocking mode it indicates how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: To echo codeinchaos's point - indeed, check that.

Comment: but: without some of the receiving code (and ideally the matching network spec, I.e. What we should expect to see on the wire) this is largely impossible to answer.

Comment: Keep the opening ceremony of the 1936 Olympics in mind when you debug this.  Not posting a code snippet is a big mistake.

Comment: @Hans - I feel ignorant for not getting the reference...

Comment: @Marc - the movie "Contact" with Jodie Foster.

Comment: @Hans - ok, it has been *years* since I last watched that...

Comment: I'm sorry, turns out I made a stupid mistake in my code. Sorry for wasting everyone's time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is hard to answer without seeing both ends of the pipe (but in particular the **sending** end). `DataAvailable` only really indicates the state of the local buffer (not the stream itself); in terms of determining the end of a stream it is largely useless (t reports something unrelated).

I *expect* this is a bug in the transmitting code. A classic error here is the following:

```
var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

When it should be:

```
var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
networkStream.Write(buffer, 0,
    (int)memoryStream.Length);
```

The first (and incorrect) version sends the garbage portion of the memory-stream's backing buffer.

Comment: Or just `memoryStream.ToArray()` in your first sample.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but I should have mentioned that I'm only replacing the legacy **receiving** end, so the sending end should be ok, as it works fine with the legacy listener.

Comment: `ToArray` allocates a new array. And for large memory streams that might not be desirable because it causes an allocation on the large object heap.